Colourful class function
Background. We're in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and I can use the principle of $\epsilon$-induction, but not (directly) the $\epsilon$-recursion.
Problem. Let $F : V \to V$, where $V$ is the class of all the sets, be a class function such that a set is blue when it has at least a red element, red otherwise.

Assuming that such a function exists, prove that's unique.
What is the color of $\omega^\omega$ (the set of the function from $\omega$ to $\omega)$,
i.e. what's the value of $F(\omega^\omega)$?
For which ordinals $\alpha$, $V_\alpha$ (in the Von Neumann universe) has as many blue elements as red ones?
Prove that the function described above exists.

My attempt.

I used $\epsilon$-induction, given $F$ and $F'$ functions with the propriety above, assuming that $\forall y \in x \ F(y) = F'(y)$, I get, that if $F(x) = R$ (red), then by definition there exists some $y \in x$ for which $F(y) = F'(y) = R$, but this, again by definition, implies $F'(x) = R$, similarly if $F(x) = B$. So by $\epsilon$-induction principle I've got uniqueness.
Given $f \in \omega^\omega$, formally $f = \{(n,f(n))\}_{n \in \omega}$, and $(n,f(n))$, by Kuratowski's encoding, is $\{\{n\},\{n,f(n)\}\}$. Now (I will use colors from now on hoping to make as clear as possible the following mess), obviously $\color{red}{0}$, and, since $\forall n \geq 1 \ 0 \in n$, $\color{blue}{n}$, this implies $\color{red}{\{n\}}$, and so $\forall n \geq 1 \ \color{blue}{\{\{n\},\{n,f(n)\}\}}$. Now we've $\color{blue}{\{0\}}$ and $\color{blue}{\{0,f(0)\}}$, which implies $\color{red}{(0,f(0))}$. So $\{\color{red}{(0,f(0)),\color{blue}{(n,f(n))}}\}_{n \geq 1} \implies \color{blue}{f}$. Finally, by the arbitrariness of $f$, we get $\color{red}{\omega^\omega}$.
My claim is that $\forall \alpha \geq \omega$ the statement is true. I've proved (tried to) it by transfinite induction as it follows:


$\boxed{\alpha = \omega}$ Let $R = \{x \in V_\omega : \ \text{$x$ is red}\}$ and $B = \{x \in V_\omega : \ \text{$x$ is blue}\}$, then the following is a bijection:
$$R \to B : x \mapsto \{x\} \in V_\omega$$
whose inverse is $\{x\} \mapsto \bigcup \mathcal P(\{x\}) = x$.
$\boxed{\alpha \implies \alpha + 1}$ Let $g^{(\alpha)} : R^{(\alpha)} \to B^{(\alpha)}$ the bijection of the subsets of red and blue elements in $V_\alpha$, which exists by inductive hypothesis, we can define:
$$g^{(\alpha + 1)} : R^{(\alpha + 1)} \to B^{(\alpha + 1)} : x \mapsto \begin{cases} g^{(\alpha)}(x) &\text{if $x \in R^{(\alpha)}$} \\\\ \{x\}&\text{otherwise} \ \text{(I think I doesn't work since $\{x\}$ not necessarily belongs to $V_{\alpha + 1}$)} \end{cases}$$
that is a bijection since union of bijection on disjoint domains.
$\boxed{\alpha = \lambda}$ since $V_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda}V_\alpha$, by the inductive hypothesis $\forall \alpha < \lambda \ \exists g^{(\alpha)} : R^{(\alpha)} \to B^{(\alpha)}$ bijection, and $\forall \beta < \alpha \ g^{(\alpha)}|_\beta = g_\beta$ (this should be proved), so we can just take:
$$g^{(\lambda)} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} g^{(\alpha)}: R^{(\lambda)} \to B^{(\lambda)}$$

(maybe in retrospect seems more correct and clean to just define by transfinite recursion a sequence of bijection constructed as above (this way we immediately have the extension propriety at limit case) and then prove by transfinite induction that works).

This is the question where I think it's intended to define $F$ by $\epsilon$-recursion but I can't (because we never mentioned $\epsilon$-recursion in class). So the idea would be to define the following sequence of class functions by transfinite recursion:
$$F_\alpha = \begin{cases}F_0 = \emptyset \\\\ F_{\alpha + 1} = F_{\alpha} \cup \{(x,H(F_\alpha[x]))\}_{x \in V_{\alpha + 1}\setminus V_\alpha} \\\\ F_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda}F_\alpha \end{cases}$$
where $H : V \to V$ is the class function defined by $H(x) = B$ if $\exists y \in x \ y = R$, $H(x) = R$ otherwise $H(x) = B$. So now we can just define $F(x) = F_{\text{rank}(x) + 1}(x)$ and prove by $\epsilon$-induction that $F(x) = B \iff \exists y \in x \ y = R$ and $F(x) = B$ otherwise.


Are my solutions correct? Especially for 3. and 4. I'm not totally convinced that everything (e.g. the definition of $F_{\alpha + 1}$) is formally correct.

Edit 1. To be more precise for question 4, I'd like to define the following class function:
$$F : V \to \{R,B\} : x \mapsto \begin{cases} B &\text{if $R \in \text{Im}(F|_x)$} \\\\ R &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
defining the class function:
$$H : V \to \{R,B\} : x \mapsto \begin{cases} B &\text{if $R \in x$} \\\\ R &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
$F$ can just be taken by $\epsilon$-recursion as $\forall x \ F(x) = H(\text{Im}(F|_x))$, and If I could assume the principle of $\epsilon$-recursion this would be it. Now, since I cannot use the $\epsilon$-recursion I define by transfinite recursion the following sequence of class functions:
$$F_{\alpha} := \begin{cases}F_0 = \emptyset \\\\ F_{\alpha + 1} = F_{\alpha} \cup \{(x,H(\underbrace{\text{Im}(F_\alpha|_x)}_{= F_\alpha[x]})) | x \in V_{\alpha + 1} \setminus V_\alpha\} \\\\ F_\lambda = \bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda} F_\gamma\end{cases}$$
and define $\forall x \ F(x) = F_{\text{rank}(x) + 1}(x)$. Since basically $F$ is "union" of compatible class functions, it is itself a well-defined class function, therefore the only thing I need to do is to prove, by $\epsilon$-induction, that $\forall x \ F(x) = H(\text{Im}(F|_x))$.
So assuming that $\forall y \in x \ F(y) = H(\text{Im}(F|_y))$ I want to prove $F(x) = H(\text{Im}(F|_x))$. By definition of $F$:
$$F(x) = F_{\text{rank}(x) + 1}(x) = H(\text{Im}(F_{\text{rank}(x)}|_x))$$
and $\text{Im}(F_{\text{rank}(x)}|_x) = F_{\text{rank}(x)}[x] = F[x] = \{F(y) | y \in x\} \overset{\text{inductive hp.}}{=} \{H(F[y]) | y \in x\} = F[x] = \text{Im}(F|_x)$. However I'm not pretty sure about these last passages.

In 3, are these really bijections? In particular, how do you know they are surjective? It sounds like the question also wants you to say something about what happens when $\alpha < \omega$.

@IzaakvanDongen it's not surjective rip, only injective.  For $V_n$ $n \in \omega$ the situation seems a little messy (at least for the cases I tried by hand), so I figured that doesn't work except for 2.

However for $V_\omega$ I can prove that $|B^{(\omega)}| = |R^{(\omega)}|$ using the map $x \mapsto {x}$ in both directions to get the two inequalities. Nevertheless I don't know if the right way to procede is without an explicit bijection in all the 3 cases.

For the cases you're trying by hand, it might help to try just counting the number of red and blue sets in $V_n$, rather than worrying about exactly which ones are red and blue. Indeed, if you know the number of red and blue sets in any finite set $X$, that immediately tells you the number of red and blue sets in $\mathcal P(X)$. (This might also give you some inspiration in the infinite case...)

@IzaakvanDongen looking better I think I've $\forall n \geq 2 |B^{(n)}| = |R^{(n)}| = |V_n|/2$, in fact, given the base cases, I can prove the induction step $n \implies n+1$ as it follows: $|B^{(n+1)}|$ is equal to the number of subsets of $V_{n}$ that contains at least one element of $R^{(n)}$, and these are $2^{|R^{(n)}| - 1} \cdot 2^{|B^{(n)}|} = 2^{|B^{(n)}| + |R^{(n)}| - 1} = 2^{|V_n| - 1} = |V_{n+1}|/2$ (obviously $|R^{(n+1)}| = |V_{n+1}| - |B^{(n+1)}| = |V_{n+1}| - |V_{n+1}|/2 = |V_{n+1}|/2$)

I am not sure I agree :). I think $|R^{(n + 1)}|$ is actually the slightly easier one to work out, but this method is fine too. Is your thinking "to specify a blue set is the same as specifying a nonempty set of red elements and a set of blue elements"? In that case I think you meant $(2^{|R^{(n)}|} - 1) \cdot 2^{|B^{(n)}|}$. You should end up concluding that for $n < \omega$ there are usually more blue sets than red sets.

@IzaakvanDongen the way I was thinking was "an element of $B^{(n+1)}$ is a subset of $V_n$ that contains at least one element from $R^{(n)}$, so, fixed one element in $R^{(n)}$, I just have to choose if the others elements of $V_n$ belongs or not to the subset"

Actually, as you hinted, maybe it's simpler to find $|R^{(n+1)}|$. Thinking $R^{(n+1)}$ as "the subsets of $V_n$ that doesn't contain any elements of $R^{(n)}$, we have $|R^{(n+1)}| = 2^{|B^{(n)}|}$, therefore $|B^{(n+1)}| = |V_{n+1}| - |R^{(n+1)}| = 2^{|V_n|} - 2^{|B^{(n)}|} = (2^{|R^{(n)}|} - 1) \cdot 2^{|B^{(n)}|}$", just like you've obtained above.

Now I'd like to define by transfinite recursion $R^{(\alpha)}$ as: $$\begin{cases} R^{(0)} = \emptyset \\ R^{(\alpha + 1)} = \mathcal P(B^{(\alpha)}) \\ R^{(\lambda)} = \bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda} R^{(\gamma)} \end{cases}$$ and $B^{(\alpha)}$ as: $$\begin{cases} B^{(0)} = \emptyset \\ B^{(\alpha + 1)} = V_{\alpha + 1} \setminus R^{(\alpha + 1)} \\ B^{(\lambda)} = \bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda} B^{(\gamma)} \end{cases}$$ and by transfinite induction prove that $\forall \alpha \geq \omega \ |R^{(\alpha)}| = |B^{(\alpha)}|$

@IzaakvanDongen doing the way I described above, I get easily that $|B^{(\omega)}| = |R^{(\omega)}|$ and $|B^{(\lambda)}| = |R^{(\lambda)}|$ for every limit ordinal $\lambda \geq \omega$, since $V_{\lambda}$ is closed under pairing axiom (therefore if $x \in V_\lambda$, then ${x} \in V_\lambda$), so I can always consider $B^{(\lambda)} \to R^{(\lambda)} : x \mapsto {x}$ and $R^{(\lambda)} \to B^{(\lambda)} : x \mapsto {x}$. Both are injective maps, thus $|R^{(\lambda)}| = |B^{(\lambda)}|$ for every limit ordinal $\lambda \geq \omega$. 1/3

Now I'm having some troubles trying to prove the statement for successor ordinals, if I suppose $|R^{(\alpha)}| = |B^{(\alpha)}|$, then $|R^{(\alpha + 1)}| = |\mathcal P(B^{(\alpha)})| = 2^{|B^{(\alpha)}|}$ and $|B^{(\alpha + 1)}| = |V_{\alpha + 1} \setminus R^{\alpha + 1}| = |\mathcal P(V_\alpha) \setminus \mathcal P(B^{(\alpha)})|$. I'd like to prove that the latter cardinality is equal to $|\mathcal P(R^{\alpha})|$, and, using the fact that $|B^{(\alpha)}| = |R^{(\alpha)}| \implies |\mathcal P(B^{(\alpha)})| = |\mathcal P(R^{(\alpha)})|$ 2/3

I finally get that: $$|B^{(\alpha + 1)}| = |\mathcal{P}(V_\alpha) \setminus \mathcal{P}(B^{(\alpha)})| =  |\mathcal P(R^{(\alpha)})| =  |\mathcal P(B^{(\alpha)})| = |R^{(\alpha + 1)}|$$ Is this the correct way to prove it (In which case I onlye have to show that $|\mathcal P(V_\alpha) \setminus \mathcal P(B^{(\alpha)})| = |\mathcal P(R^{\alpha})|$)? Or am I wrong/the definitions above are incorrect? (sorry to bother you all the time :)) 3/3

No worries about bothering! This looks absolutely right to me. You are almost there. To find the cardinality of $B^{(\alpha + 1)}$ for infinite $\alpha$, I think it is profitable to look at it as an abstract "find the cardinality" question. You should try and prove that the cardinality you want it to have is a lower bound and an upper bound, by making liberal use of cardinal arithmetic and all your other hypotheses. If you work it out, again feel free to post a short summary as an answer below if you like. (Also, don't forget to say something about $\alpha < \omega$)

@IzaakvanDongen I'll gladly make a short summary as soon as I'm certain about the answers to 3 and 4! For now, I think it's easier directly prove that $\forall \alpha \geq \omega \ |R^{(\alpha)}| = |B^{(\alpha)}| = |V_\alpha|$, thus for $\alpha = \omega$ the result is still valid with the proof above, and generally, for limit ordinals, once proved that $|R^{(\lambda)}| = |B^{(\lambda)}|$, since $|R^{(\lambda)}| + |B^{(\lambda)}| = |V_\lambda|$, we have $|R^{(\lambda)}| = |B^{(\lambda)}| = |V_\lambda|$. Lastly for successor ordinals, assuming $|R^{(\alpha)}| = |B^{(\alpha)}| = |V_\alpha|$ 1/2

I've $|R^{(\alpha + 1)}| = |\mathcal P(B^{(\alpha)})| = 2^{|B^{(\alpha)}|} = 2^{|V_\alpha|} = |V_{\alpha + 1}|$ , and obviously $|B^{(\alpha + 1)}| = |V_{\alpha + 1} \setminus R^{(\alpha + 1)}| \leq |V_{\alpha + 1}|$. For the lower bound  we can notice that $\mathcal P(R^{(\alpha)}) \subseteq B^{(\alpha + 1)}$, and so $|V_{\alpha + 1}| = 2^{|V_\alpha|} = 2^{|R^{(\alpha)}|} = |\mathcal P(R^{(\alpha)})| \leq |B^{(\alpha + 1)}|$. This should work and conclude question 3, am I right? 2/2

Yep, that works. Nice. What you've written for 4 looks like it or something very similar will work (I haven't checked all the details). It seems like you're doing more work than you need to, though. Since you've already done the work of defining $B^{(\alpha)}$ and $R^{(\alpha)}$, it seems to me that you can just use these to give a very short and simple definition of "the class of all blue/red sets", and hence of $F$!

@IzaakvanDongen so you're suggesting to just define the proper classes of red and blue sets: $$\overline R := \bigcup_{\alpha \in \text{Ord}} R^{(\alpha)} \qquad \overline B := \bigcup_{\alpha \in \text{Ord}} B^{(\alpha)} $$ now, since $\forall x , x \in V_\alpha$, for some ordinal $\alpha$, and $V_{\alpha} = R^{(\alpha)} \sqcup B^{(\alpha)}$, we have $V = \overline R \sqcup \overline B$. From this I just define: $$F : V \to {B,R} : \underbrace{x}{\in V\alpha}\mapsto \begin{cases} R &\text{if $x \in R^{(\alpha)}$} \\ B &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Yep, that's right. The idea is basically that defining a class indicator function for a class $C$ is only as hard as defining $C$ itself.

@IzaakvanDongen uh very nice, thank you! Now I'll write the recap answer, if it's possible (I completely understand that you've better things to do, so if you can't that's not a problem) could you take a more detailed look at my answer too (since It seems to be a recurrent idea (In my professor's past exams) to make the $\epsilon$-recursion from the transfinite recursion + Von Neumann hierarchy, I was trying to understand all the details of this method, especially because I cannot find other exercises solved using this particular idea)?

Summary of the discussion in the comments of OP
Questions 1 and 2 should be ok. For question 3, if $\alpha < \omega$, i.e. $\alpha = n \in \omega$, one can prove by induction that $\forall n \in \omega\ R^{(n+1)} = \mathcal P(B^{(n)})$ and hence $B^{(n+1)} = V_{n+1} \setminus R^{(n+1)}$. So we have: $|R^{(n+1)}| = 2^{|B^{(n)}|}$ and $|B^{(n+1)}| = 2^{|V_n|} - 2^{|B^{(n)}|} = 2^{|B^{(n)}| + |R^{(n)}|} - 2^{|B^{(n)}|} = (2^{|R^{(n)}|}-1) \cdot 2^{|B^{(n)}|}$, again by induction it's possible to prove:
$$\forall n \geq 4 \ |B^{(n)}| > |R^{(n)}|$$
we can check by hand that $|B^{(0)}| = |R^{(0)}|$, $|B^{(1)}| < |R^{(1)}|$, $|B^{(2)}| = |R^{(2)}|$ and $|B^{(3)}| = |R^{(3)}|$. Therefore if $\alpha < \omega$, the statement is true only for $\boxed{\alpha = 0,2,3}$. Assuming that $\alpha \geq \omega$ it's again possible to explicitly write the blue and red sets at every level of Von Neumann hierarchy as it follows:
$$R^{(\alpha)} := \begin{cases} R^{(0)} = \emptyset \\\\ R^{(\alpha + 1)} = \mathcal P(B^{(\alpha)}) \\\\ R^{(\lambda)} = \bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda} R^{(\gamma)} \end{cases} \qquad B^{(\alpha)} := \begin{cases} B^{(0)} = \emptyset \\\\ B^{(\alpha + 1)} = V_{\alpha + 1} \setminus R^{(\alpha + 1)} \\\\ B^{(\lambda)} = \bigcup_{\gamma < \lambda} B^{(\gamma)} \end{cases}$$
now it's possible to prove by transfinite induction that $\forall \alpha \geq \omega \ |R^{(\alpha)}| = |B^{(\alpha)}| = |V_\alpha|$ (check the discussion in the comments for more detalis), thus the statement it's also true for $\boxed{\alpha \geq \omega}$. 
About question 4, referring to the definition of $R^{(\alpha)}$ and $B^{(\alpha)}$ given above, we can define the proper classes of red and blue sets:
$$\overline R := \bigcup_{\alpha \in \text{Ord}} R^{(\alpha)} \qquad \overline B := \bigcup_{\alpha \in \text{Ord}} B^{(\alpha)}$$
and define $F$ as it follows:
$$F : V \to \{B,R\} : \underbrace{x}_{\in V_\alpha}\mapsto \begin{cases} R &\text{if $x \in R^{(\alpha)}$} \\\\ B &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
(thanks to @IzaakvanDongen for all the helpful suggestions).

Nice. I had a look at your other approach for 4. I think $F(x)=H(\mathrm{Im}(F|x))$ is actually easier than you're making it. (It should be a bit of a warning sign that $F(x)$ appears twice in your chain of equalities). I think all you need to argue is $H(\mathrm{Im}(F|x))=H(\mathrm{Im}(F{\mathrm{rank}(x)}|x))$. This is just because for any $y\in x$, we have $F(y)=F{\mathrm{rank}(y)+1}(y)=F{\mathrm{rank}(x)}(y)$, because $\mathrm{rank}(y)+1\le\mathrm{rank}(x)$ and each $F_\alpha$ agrees with all previously defined values. So no $\epsilon$-induction required. The rest looks OK!

@IzaakvanDongen ah lol, perfect, thank you!!
